# React leaflet bouncing marker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, css-animations

I have a react leaflet map that is more or less built as a component as below:

```
    <>
      <MapContainer
        center={[startLat, startLen]}
        more props...
      >
        <TileLayer
          url={`...`}
          attribution='...'
        />

        {data?.length > 0 &&
          data.map((item) => {
            return (
              <Marker
                key={item.name}
                position={[item.lat, item.lang]}
                more props...
              >
              </Marker>
            );
          })}
      </MapContainer>
    </>
```

I would like some of the markers to be animated. Doesn't really matter how, they just need to stand out. I found a leaflet plugin that looks very useful: https://github.com/hosuaby/Leaflet.SmoothMarkerBouncing

But to be honest I don't know how to apply it to this `Marker` React component. Is it possible? Or is there another easy way of making one marker on the map move/stand out?

Comment: Hi, have you found solution? I also would like to use it with React Leaflet